# Laravel, inertiajs and vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am working on a project using laravel, inertiajs and vuejs. I am always getting 404 | NOT FOUND error when I try deleting user from the database. I want to delete the user when I click the button with deleteUser method. What might be wrong?

Route

```
Route::delete('/destroy/{user}', [AppController::class, 'destroy'])->name('users.destroy');
```

Controller

```
public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        $user->delete();
    }
```

vue

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
            <div class="flex bg-white border px-6 py-6 rounded-sm max-w-2xl mx-auto mt-6">
                <img :src="user.profile_photo_url" alt="Image" class="h-14 w-14 rounded-full"/>
                <div class="flex-1">
                    <span class="ml-2 text-lg text-black font-semibold">
                        {{user.name}}
                    </span>
                    <span class="float-right ml-2">
                        <button @click="deleteUser" class="border border-purple-300 px-4 py-1 rounded-full text-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-600 hover:text-white hover:border-transparent">Follow</button>
                    </span>
                    <br/>
                    <span class="ml-2 text-gray-500 font-medium">
                        Laravel and Vuejs
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import AppLayout from '@/Layouts/AppLayout'

    export default {
        components: {
            AppLayout,
        },

        props: ['users'],

        data(){
            return{
                form:{
                    user_id:''
                }
            }
        },

        methods:{
            deleteUser() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this contact?')) {
                this.$inertia.delete(`/destroy/${this.users.id}`)
                .then(() => {
                })
            }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is your full url ? generated by laravel

Comment: in browser your using with `public` url or `pretty url ?

Comment: localhost:8000/users is my url

Comment: Is your request method "DELETE"?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to your method like this:

```
<button @click="deleteUser(user)">Delete</button>

methods: {
deleteUser: function(user){
this.$inertia.delete(this.route('users.destroy'), user))
}}
```

This is because your delete method in user controller is asking for a user variable.

Answer (score 0):

The delete action should accept the current user from the iteration as an argument.

```
<button @click="delete(user)" class="border border-purple-300 px-4 py-1 rounded-full text-purple-600 hover:bg-purple-600 hover:text-white hover:border-transparent">Follow</button>
```

Then you should pass the user id as a parameter for your delete route:

```
methods: {
    delete(user) {
        if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this contact?')) {
            this.$inertia.delete(`/destroy/${user.id}`);
        }
    }
}
```